# Magento - How to show all products of a category in only one page

Tags: magento

I want to show all the products of a category in only one page, without the toolbar pager.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the solution in Magento backend,

it's like this :

Configuration > catalog > frontend > Allow All Products per Page > yes ;)

Comment: Nice, using `0` as the `Products per Page Default value` will then show all products per default.

Answer (score 3):

open this file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php

go to function getLimit() and replace line 745 :

```
$limit = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getLimitPage();
```

by :

```
$limit = 'all';
```

it is recomanded to override this function. do must making any changes to Magento Core.